# Taxonomy Terms - Views Services

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, services

I have created a view of type service that fetches Taxonomy terms, response as following :

---

```
{
  data: [
    {
      taxonomy_term_data_name: "Child Term",
      tid: "6",
      parent_id: "37",
      order: "0"
    },
    {
      taxonomy_term_data_name: "Parent Term",
      tid: "37",
      order: "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

the taxonomy has parent/child in it, as the response show, I get the parent_id in the response for childrens but not for parent terms, is there any change that I can set the parent_id to 0 for parent terms ?

I have to mention that I am a Java developer, and new to Drupal.

Comment: @FreeRadical I have edited my question hopefully it is more clear somehow now. thanks